# Showing that if $\mu$ is an ergodic probability measure and $\nu\ll\mu$ then $\nu(A)=\int_A fd\mu$ with $f$ being constant $\mu$-a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, absolute-continuity

Let $(X,B,\mu)$ be a measure space and $T:X\to X$ be a transformation such that $\mu$ is ergodic w.r.t. $T$. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity#Formal_definition) for further details of the ergodicity setting. I am looking to understand the claim that if $\nu$ is any measure which is absolutely continuous with respect to a probability measure $\mu$, then $\nu$ is a constant multiple of $\mu$.

Currently I am stuck at using the assumed invariance/ergodicity of $\mu$. To be precise, if $\nu\ll\mu$ then the Radon-Nikodym theorem guarantees the existence of $f\in L^1(\mu)$ such that $\nu(A) = \int_Afd\mu$ for any $\nu$-measurable set $A$. Now we ought to show that $f = C$ $\mu$-a.e. in $X$. Since I don't know what such a constant $C$ might be my idea was to use contradiction: So if $f$ is not constant $\mu$-a.e. there exists some $N\in B$ such that $f$ is not constant on $N$ and $\mu(N) > 0$. By assumption $\mu(N) = \mu(T^{-1}(N))$ and this is probably the part where the contradiction assumption should kick in: I would need to conclude that somehow $\mu(N)\neq \mu(T^{-1}(N))$ by using the definition of $\nu$. But

$$\nu(N) = \int_Nf(x)d\mu(x) = \int_X 1_N(x)f(x)d\mu(x)$$

and

$$\nu(T^{-1}(N)) = \int_{T^{-1}(N)}f(x)d\mu(x) = \int_X1_N(T(x))f(x)d\mu(x)$$

and I don't see a priori anything connecting $\nu(N)$ to $\nu(T^{-1}(N))$. What should I do?

Comment: Hi, Lets define a measure $p(A) = \int_A g d\mu$. Now $p<<\mu$. why should $g = constant$ since its not constant by definition? Since $\nu$ is similar to $p$, i think you are missing some key condition like may be you want $T$ to be measure preserving for $\nu$ also ? in which case the conclusion may be easily reached.

Comment: Check out the answer to this related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604019/if-g-is-invariant-under-an-ergodic-map-then-its-almost-everywhere-constant

Comment: @JoshKeneda I see! Well, the only thing I am now missing is how to show that $f$ is invariant under $T$. To be precise, we are done if $f=\chi_E$ is invariant under $T$. From $\mu(E)=\mu(T^{-1}(E))$ we get $\int_X(\chi_E-\chi_{T^{-1}(E)})d\mu=\int_X(\chi_{T^{-1}(E)}-\chi_E)d\mu=0$. But I don't know how to conclude from this that $\chi_E(x)=\chi_E(T(x))$ $\mu$-almost everywhere in $X$.

Comment: It can't be true that any generic $\chi_E$ is invariant under $T$, because that's the same as saying that $E$ is an invariant subset, and ergodic transformations shouldn't have non-trivial invariant subsets.  I think Balaji is right - you're probably missing the assumption that $\nu$ is also preserved by $T$ or something.